# Float round up to 2 decimals java

Tags: java, floating-point, decimal, rounding, bigdecimal

I'm trying to round a float up to 2 decimals.

I've 2 float values:

```
1.985
29.294998
```

Both of them will need to be rounded up so I end up with the following:

```
1.99
29.30
```

When I use the following method:

```
public static Float precision(int decimalPlace, Float d) {

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(d));
    bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    return bd.floatValue();
  }
```

Te result is:

```
1.99
29.29
```

Comment: A float is not an effective way of storing a decimal number.  Whenever you want to keep track of a number with a certain number of decimal places, they should be _kept_ as a `BigDecimal` and not converted back to `float`.

Comment: ROUND_UP use instead of that

Comment: If you want decimal places, use a decimal radix. A float doesn't have decimal paces.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are using `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP`, `29.294998` is rounded to `29.29`. You might want to use `BigDecimal.ROUND_UP` instead.

Check [BigDecimal doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for more informations on each rounding available.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this

`bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);`

Use

`bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);`

About ROUND_CEILING

> Rounding mode to round towards positive infinity. If the BigDecimal is
>   positive, behaves as for ROUND_UP; if negative, behaves as for
>   ROUND_DOWN. Note that this rounding mode never decreases the
>   calculated value.

You can use `DecimalFormat` if you want.

Answer (score 3):

Since you always want to round up, what you want is simply not [`BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_UP) but instead [`BigDecimal.ROUND_UP`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_UP) or [`BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_CEILING).

Use [`BigDecimal.ROUND_UP`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_UP) if you want *negative* numbers to round down (-29.294998 to -29.30).
Use [`BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_CEILING) if you want *negative* numbers to round up (-29.294998 to -29.29).

With positive numbers, they will both do the rounding you're trying to do (ie round up)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `ROUND_HALF_UP`, when you should be using `ROUND_UP`. `ROUND_HALF_UP` rounds to the closest number with the given precision, rounding up to break ties (ie 1.235 rounds to 1.24)

Answer (score 0):

ROUND_HALP_UP

> Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up. Behaves as for RoundingMode.UP if the discarded fraction is >= 0.5; otherwise, behaves as for RoundingMode.DOWN. Note that this is the rounding mode commonly taught at school.

One of the checks that is done is wether the magnitude of the remainder being dropped (2*4998) is greater than the divisor (10000). In this case it is not so its determined to be closer to the lower end. If you try 29.295001 that rounds to 29.3 for ROUND_HALP_UP .